# Three.js - stop rendering scene when not visible / out of viewport

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm making a website that uses a lot of js and animations and first section is fullscreen three.js scene which is moving with mouse movement. Scene itself is fine but everyting is being rendered all the time even when im not looking at the three.js webgl canvas and it's making performace problems, while other animations are happening lower on the website.

I need to stop rendering scene completely while scene is not in viewport and that will boost pewrformacne drastically.

Here is render function:

```
const render = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);


    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.05;
    camera.position.y += (mouseY * -1 - camera.position.y) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    const t = Date.now() * 0.001;
    const rx = Math.sin(t * 0.6) * 0.5;
    const ry = Math.sin(t * 0.3) * 0.5;
    const rz = Math.sin(t * 0.2) * 0.5;
    group.rotation.x = rx;
    group.rotation.y = ry;
    group.rotation.z = rz;
    textMesh.rotation.x = rx;
    textMesh.rotation.y = ry;
    textMesh.rotation.z = rx; // :) 

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
render();
```

Here's what i tried to add to stop rendering (found this on another thread here but cant make it work)

```
var stopRendering = (af) => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(af);
    isRendering = false;
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;

    //element is almost about to be visible, time to start rendering
    if (scrollPosition >= ("#canvas-wrapper")-50) {
        if (everythingIsLoaded && !isRendering) {
            render();
            console.log('render has been started');
        } else {
            //wait until everythingIsLoaded is true
        }
    //element is not visible, stop rendering
    } else {
        //need to stop rendering here!
        if (render) {
            stopRendering(render);
            console.log('render has been halted');
        }
    }
});
```

[**Here is full codepen**](https://codepen.io/najkenko/pen/eYzpJmN)

Another thing is, but that shouldnt be a problem, i'm using [locomotive scroll library](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll) for scroll and viewport visibility detection and this library is highjacking scroll so basic "scroll" is not working.

Main goal of pausing of rendering is to drastically boost performance.

[**WORKING SOLUTION HERE**](https://codepen.io/najkenko/pen/eYzpJmN) in case someone finds this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to get an event when an element is on/off screen.

```js
const statusElem = document.querySelector('.status');

const onScreen = new Set();
const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      onScreen.add(entry.target);
    } else {
      onScreen.delete(entry.target);
    }
  });
  statusElem.textContent = onScreen.size
    ? `on screen: ${[...onScreen].map(e => e.textContent).join(', ')}`
    : 'none';
});

document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(elem => {
  intersectionObserver.observe(elem);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: xx-large;
}
.test {
  padding: 3em;
  background: orange;
}
.status {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: medium;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">a</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quaestio principes ea eos. Feugait ocurreret mea ea. Wisi altera intellegebat vix an, sed iuvaret tincidunt adipiscing ea, at debet iudico labores eum. Mucius adversarium vix no, nec amet contentiones ea. Sea noluisse mandamus referrentur cu. Facilisis similique quo eu, pri alii noluisse efficiantur in.
</p>
<div class="test">b</div>
<p>
Sea cu vidit neglegentur, te pro maluisset accusamus, ad est diceret iudicabit. Honestatis referrentur no vim, per no putant prompta antiopam. Est singulis vituperata no, adhuc nonumy consectetuer quo cu, quas primis at mel. No doming fabulas admodum est. Cu usu ornatus principes constituam, sint petentium at quo.
</p>
<div class="test">c</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```

You can then use that to start/stop rendering those elements

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Everything is working. I also successfully implemented stop and start of rendering, here is final working codepen in case anybody finds this question, since i was googling for quite a while and coulnd find good solution: https://codepen.io/najkenko/pen/eYzpJmN

Comment: @gnam found the wierdes bug in that code, maybe you can help me since you already here. I have no idea why is it happening, but this is happening.
-When i reaload that pen a scoll down stop/start render works
-But, when i first move mouse on canvas and then scroll down to stop render, that stop render does not work at all and i have to hit run again

Comment: Also wierd is, when i first scroll to stop render and then restart it with scroll back up, i can move my mouse on canvas and stop/starp works like it should, it just doest work when the first thing i do is move my mouse on canvas, seems like some hierarchy issue, tried to fix it but failed

Comment: The code in your pen is adding `<div class="test">` to the observer. You want to add your canvas to the observer. For example `intersectionObserver.observe(renderer.domElement)`

Comment: problem is somewhere else, even if i add that class to canvas wrapper like here https://codepen.io/najkenko/pen/ZEObKvv it still has the same weird behaviour. When i scroll down before i move mouse, stopping and restarting works, but when i first move mouse and then scroll out of view, stopping and restarting doesn't work :/

Comment: You need to pay attention to the code and not just blindly copy and paste. IntersectionObserver observes the elements you tell it to observe. The example in the snippet above has it observing every element with class "test". You need change those lines to observe the elements you want to observe. Delete the entire `document.querySelector("test").forEach(......)` part and replace it with `intersectionObserver.observe(renderer.domElement)`

Comment: thanks, ye i know, it was just for tensting and obseving worked even when i added test class to canvas. But that problem with starting and stopping of rendering if i furst move mouse on canvas is still there and i have no idea why or how is it possible, since if i scroll first, it works fine

Comment: I am not able to repo your issue. The pen I posted always stops appropriate regardless of whether I move the mouse on the canvas first.